# isotope Js not showing animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using isotope Js to show filtered elements , there is filter that contains a lot of items so it is not showing the animation as it is under the visible content

example of piece of code (This code snippet is taken from other question found on stackoverflow) :

```
<div class="demos-filter">
<div class="filter-button-group">
    <a data-filter="*">showAll</a>
    <a data-filter=".apples">topmenu</a>
    <a data-filter=".oranges">onepage</a>

</div>
```

Please inform me if you need more details .

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I have just found solution for that

```
appelationIsotope.arrange({
sortBy:'random'
});
```

Just we need to add `sortBy : 'random'`
Link of Documentation :
Under SortBy
https://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html